# $scope.$watch a particular object inside an array - Angular JS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

My schema is as below.

```
Orders {
    customers[{
        customerId: String,
        address: String,
        onlineOrder [{
            items...
        }],
        directOrder [{
            items...
        }]
    }]
}
```

Now, for some reason(too big to explain) I want a watch function, for any items added to onlineOrder[items] array.

For that, I couldnot write the function like,

$scope.$watch('order.customer[i].onlineOrder[j]')

where i and j are array indices.

Because I want the watch function to be triggered for the current 'i'th customer, for every add/delete/modify of 'j'th online order item

I need help in this.

Comment: why not control the access to the arrays with methods? then you will know exactly what is changing, and it's way more efficient than a `$watch` in that case. - But I'd say take a look at `$watchCollection` possibly, not sure if it would work for you though in this case.

Comment: can you please explain a bit in detail. I couldnt get fully.

Comment: Why doesn't `$scope.$watch('order.customer[i].onlineOrder[j]', callback, true)` work? Whenever you add (undefined->something), delete (something->undefined), modify (something->something else) there is a change and watch will notice... you have to include the `true` at the end though otherwise the watch function may not notice the latter case unless the object is completely exchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest controlling the access to the array you need to watch, so you can be aware of the changes yourself, without the inefficiencies of a `$watch`. I'm not sure what all you are trying to do with that object, and it what ways it could be manipulated, but lets say it has items added by a user clicking a button(`ng-click`).

To control access you could then have the button call a function like so:

```
<button ng-click="doWork(orderId, customerId, newOnlineOrder)">Add Order</button>

//in your controller
$scope.doWork = function (orderId, customerId, onlineOrder) {
  //do some work to ensure the order is good, then add it to the collection:
  orders[orderId].customers[customerId].push(onlineOrder);
  //notify anything that needs to know it changed
  notifyMyCode(onlineOrder);
};
```

In this way, you easily know what changed, and you control it being changed maliciously, or by accident, you can validate data before updating your model, and you will know faster and with more certainty that a `$watch` expression because you control the only way to change the object.